# RESTful web service in cakePHP

Tags: php, web-services, cakephp, rest, cakephp-1.3

I followed the tutorial on [this website](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1238/REST) which explains how to setup REST with cakePHP, but after I did all this, when I call my controller in the browser (for example I have a PostsController which has the default CRUD actions), I still get html as my response (not xml). It seems like the view file that's being called is the one in `app/views/posts/index.ctp` instead of the one I placed in `app/views/posts/xml/index.ctp`.

Can anybody tell me what else I am missing here please?

Thank you

Comment: http://localhost/my_application/my_controller/my_action

Comment: I think I'll go spend my time with less sarcastic posters.

Answer (score 3):

What version of cakePHP are you using? If you are using versions 2.x, the solution is very simple.

1. Make sure you include this line in your controller

   ```
   public $components = array('RequestHandler');
   ```
2. Go into your app/Config/routes.php and add the following lines BEFORE the line with `require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';` :

   ```
   Router::mapResources('examples');
   Router::parseExtensions('xml');
   ```

   Where examples is essentially just the name of your view.
3. Be sure to enter the your url with the xml extension.

   ```
   url/controller.xml
   ```

This should do the trick. Including the RequestHandler component, when "used in conjunction with Router::parseExtensions() RequestHandler, will automatically switch the layout and view files to those that match the requested type"

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an xml layout? You might need to just create a blank layout and in the view set the layout to the xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting something like this in your controller function (or even better in the beforeFiler):

```
if(@($this->request->isXML() || $this->request->params['ext'] == 'xml')) {
    $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
}
```

Also make sure in Config/routes.php is

```
Router::parseExtensions('xml');
```

Comment: Are you putting a .xml at the end of your url?